# Junit @Runwith - with different Runners ; how does it work

Tags: junit, mockito, springrunner

I am trying to understand how `@RunWith` can accept different types of `Runners`. How does Junit understand or accept a different Runner and flex to run with a different runners (like SpringRunner , MockitoRunner), which are written by different vendors altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class must extend the abstract class `Runner`.

From the [javadoc](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.13/org/junit/runner/RunWith.html)

```
Element Detail
value
public abstract Class<? extends Runner> value
Returns:
a Runner class (must have a constructor that takes a single Class to run)
```

Any vendor can write a class which extends [`Runner`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.13/org/junit/runner/Runner.html) and Junit 4 can use it. Junit 4 depends only on the abstract class.